# What is the most underrated or little known but useful algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, theory

I'm looking for the one algorithm or data structure which is so unknown yet useful that you think it's a horrible oversight by the computer science or programming community.  If *only* we could all learn this one thing, a lot of good would be done to many future programs.

The best one I can come up with is interpolation search, which only very few programmers know, whereas everyone knows binary search.  I think there's little doubt that searching an ordered list quickly is a pretty useful and fundamenteal algorithm.

The two are almost identical to implement - so that's not an issue.

It performs O(log(log(n))) on uniformly distributed data, versus binary searches O(log(n)).  That means searching 4 billion numbers requires only 5 probes vs. 32, that's a LOT better!

On non-perfectly uniform data, it still performs really well most of the time.  Only when the data is really skewed is it as bad as binary search or worse.  It's O(n) worst case when the data is highly skewed, but this is pretty uncommon in most real world situations.

Even still, one can construct a even/odd algorithm to alternate between the two and get the worst case of binary search with the average case of interpolation search to mitigate the extreme situations.

There is really no good reason this is so overlooked by most programmers/libraries.

Can anyone else beat that?

Comment: I think this is a good question... unless there are duplicates around. +1

Comment: sounds like a rep troll; not a real question IMO

Comment: I couldn't find any... but I'm happy to remove it if there are!

Comment: @Mitch, That's why I used the example of interpolation search - did you know about interpolation search?  If not, look it up in Wikipedia please, it's really no more complex than binary search but often much faster.  Don't you think it's true that many programs/programmers could benefit if only it were better known?!?

Comment: @Chris: I did thanks. I don't believe this is what SO is for. But that's just my opinion....

Comment: @Chris: you neglected to mention that the worst case performance(though unlikely) is O(N)

Comment: Suggestion: community mode like all the other "hidden features of Foo", "best Bar ever", ... questions.

Comment: Apologies, but this question fails the "detailed and specific" FAQ guideline imo. You're not trying to solve a specific problem, but instead are trawling for "interesting" code snippets. Should be CW at least

Comment: @Mitch, fair enough. I added O(N) explicitly.  My main point of this question was that there could be many other examples which *I* don't know about and really should, so I'm eager to poll people smarter than I on the subject.  Can you think of something more overlooked yet useful than IS? :)

Comment: "5 probes vs 32 for 4 billion entries" may sound like a huge improvement but it's along the lines of "I have an algorithm that only takes 1e-7 seconds while the next best one takes a whopping 1e-5 seconds, making mine 100 times faster". There's little difference between the two absolute figures. That level of improvement only becomes relevant as 'n' approaches truly huge numbers.

Comment: @Pax: I'm glad someone pointed that out!

Comment: @Pax: Ok, so you're arguing about the utility of interpolation search over binary search.  I think that given a "probe" can be a pretty costly exercise (disk access, nework access, etc.) it's actually quite significant, but this is why I asked the question!  Can you think of something more underrated?

Comment: @Binary: Enough of you seem to be pretty upset about this - so I made it CW (which I didn't know about before, BTW) - do I need to do anything else?  Or am I kosher now? :)

Comment: good question indeed. And as usual it's closed for not being 'real' :-O

Comment: @MadH: Thanks for your support, hopefully you help throw in a vote to reopen it!  I would love to get back to the business of finding more diamonds in the rough as well.  I think it's ironic that none of these folks who have picked on my example have offered anything better! :)

Comment: Voted to reopen. This question should see the light of day soon, but probably won't get as much exposure.

Comment: Re-opened (but I was still in two minds about it - you get the benefit of the doubt). Best of luck with your answers.

Answer (score 6):

I nominate smoothsort.  In-place, time complexity O(n log n) worst case / O(n) best case.

Comment: Not a bad nomination!  I had never heard of this one either - and it does fix a major problem with heapsort.  I think mergesort is generally preferable to heapsort generally because it better exploits locality while sorting.  I did a little checking and found mixed results on whether it's better in practice or not though - have you see this paper discussing it's performance characteristics?  I couldn't find any others.  http://iwi.eldoc.ub.rug.nl/FILES/root/1991/InfProcLettBron/1991InfProcLettBron.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)/[ternary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tree) ... Quick prefix matches! I've certainly used them more than heaps or explicit linked list structures (implicit linked lists with "next"s are often useful, though).

Comment: The whole field of tries is much-neglected. Early, naive, tries are memory-hungry, and not terribly fast, but there has been some superb work in more recent years; see Judy trees, burst trees, fusion trees, and more. They are now serious competition to any kind of binary tree, and even hashtables in some situations.

Answer (score 2):

Another nomination for smoothsort.  It's theoretically quite beautiful and is asymptotically as good as it gets.

In case you're curious, I wrote up an [explanation](http://www.keithschwarz.com/smoothsort) of how the sort works and where it comes from on my personal site.

Also, I totally agree that interpolation search is really awesome.  I'm glad someone else has heard of this one. :-)